# Why is my noindex tag not working?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, noindex

I've implemented a no index tag in my staging website header because I've realized it was being indexed. But when we run this page in screaming frog or this tool here to verify the noidex is present and functioning, it shows that it's not.

But if you view the source of the page, the code is present in the head tag. And unfortunately we've seen instances where Google is indexing pages we've noindexed. Any thoughts on the example above or why this is happening in Google?[image]

HTTP Header:

[image]

Comment: Do you disallow anything in your robots.txt?

Comment: Are you also sending a (conflicting) `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header?

Comment: @MrWhite I've added in my comment what I see in the HTTP response header

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I typed my website and robots.txt at the end and here is what I got : User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: "or this tool here" - What is "this tool here"? "it shows that it's not." - What exactly does "it" report?